# How do I reference the object being created?

Tags: java, inheritance, javafx, this, anonymous-class

In the middle of building my FXMLDocumentController class I needed to use a lambda expression that creates a new object with some @overrides, in that @overrides I need to reference my object, how to do it?

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        listViewArtigosMercado.setCellFactory((ListView<String> param) -> new ListCell<String>(){
            @Override
            public void updateItem(String name, boolean empty){
                super.updateItem(name,empty);
                if (name.equals("Vender")){
                    setText(name);
                    ((Node)this).setId("id");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want that my `this` keyword whether reference itself to my new `ListCell<String>` rather than `FXMLDocumentController`
How reference my new class inside of implementation?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this error. The only compiler issue in your code seems to be that `listViewArtigosMercado` is not declared in `FXMLDocumentController`. BTW: Note that multiple items can be used with the same `ListCell`. You may end up with cells containing items other than `"Vender"` unless you add a `else` clause fixing this. (Same for the `text` property). Furthermore cells can be empty. In this case `item` (`name`) is `null` which results in a `NullPointerException` in your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Insted of `(Node)this` use `Node.this`. You can get the current object of the outer class by calling `OuterClass.this`.

Then you can just call it's method:

```
(OuterClass.this).methodOfOuterClass();
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the cast and `this`, it's unambiguous call referring to a parent's method:

```
setId("id");
```

Look carefully at how you are using `setText(name);`. The method is from `Labeled`, but you neither used `this` nor cast it to that class, simply because there was no need for that. `ListCell` is a `Labeled` as well as a `Node`.

Answer (score 0):

Here, As I can see you are using `lambda` function inside the initialize method as below.

```
listViewArtigosMercado.setCellFactory((ListView<String> param) -> new ListCell<String>(){
      @Override
      public void updateItem(String name, boolean empty){
      super.updateItem(name,empty);
      if (name.equals("Vender")){
          setText(name);
              ((Node)this).setId("id");
          }
      }
 });
```

Lambda does not treat as the anonymous class. So the scope of the lambda function is limited to that particular enclosing close. `this` is to reference for that particular scop only. so you can not write `this.setId('Id');` inside setCelFactor lambda because it does not contain `setId` method.

Here lambda is treated as a child class of the parent class. In your case, its child class of `FXMLDocumentController` so it has an accessibility of all public method of parent class so you can use `setID` or other methods direct without any reference.

Comment: Of course `this.setId("id")` can be used in the `updateItem` method. Inside the lambda experssion an anonymus class extending `ListCell` is created and from the methods of this anonymus class `this` refers to the `ListCell`. The cast is unnecessary, but not wrong. (Of course `'Id'` is not valid java syntax so `this.setId('Id');` won't work)